# Ternary "Lie structure"

Tags: lie-algebras

One of the motivation of the theory of Lie Algebras is that every associative algebra $A$ is a LA when the bracket is defined by $[a,b]=ab-ba$ : this is skew-symmetric and satisfies the Jacobi identity $[[a,b],c]+[[b,c],a]+[[c,a],b]=0$. Conversely, every abstract LA can be embedded into an associative algebra (its *envelopping algebra*). And for some good reason, one is really interested in sub-LAs rather than sub-algebras. A similar attitude, with different motivation lead to the notion of Jordan algebras.

> If $A$ is an associative algebra, one may consider instead the *ternary* bracket $$[a,b,c]_3=abc+bca+cab-acb-cba-bac.$$ 
>   Does $[.,.,.]_3$ satisfy non-trivial identities, besides skew-symmetry? Is there any theory of abstract objects, vector spaces endowed which a ternary skew-symmetric product satisfying these identities?

More generally, we may consider a $d$-bracket, which bears the name of *standard non-commutative polynomial* in $d$ non-commuting variables. For $d=2$, it is nothing but the standard bracket. When $d=2p$, the $d$-bracket does satisfy non-trivial identies, for instance
$$\sum_{i\in\frak A_7}[[a_{i_1},a_{i_2},a_{i_3},a_{i_4}],a_{i_5},a_{i_6},a_{i_7}]=0,\qquad\forall a_1,\ldots,a_7\in A.$$
I don't know if something non-trivial exists when $d$ is odd.

Comment: Have you checked if these are $L_\infty$ structures?

Comment: (Ginzburg and Berger have studied a family of algebras, called antisymmetrizer algebras. The *thirds* one is the quotient of the free algebra on three generators $a$, $b$, $c$ modulo what you write as $[abc]_3$; the algebra is encodes then properties of triads of elements which "ternary-Lie-commute". The algebra is $3$-Koszul in the sense of Berger, so quite special: maybe you can extract information from that fact)

Comment: If you remove $bca-acb$ (that is, the only two terms with $c$ in the middle) then you get a Lie triple system http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2372102?uid=3737952&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21100790345141 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_system#Lie_triple_systems

Comment: You might be interested in my answer to a previous MO question concerning n-Lie algebras: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49437/why-are-so-few-operations-with-arity-bigger-than-2/49443#49443

Answer (score 16, accepted):

["Identities for the ternary commutator"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869398974336) by Bremner classifies all such identities up to degree 7. A recent exposition can also be found in ["Ternutator Identities"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1738) by C. Devchand, D. Fairlie, J. Nuyts, G. Weingart. Similar identities for n-ary commutators are proven in ["Multi-operator brackets acting thrice"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2759) by T. Curtright, X. Jin, L. Mezincescu. I don't know if there is an accepted definition for what a Lie n-ary algebra should be for $n\geq 3$ (not to be confused with Lie n-algebras from nlab). For $n=3$ the most standard object one encounters are [Lie triple systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_system#Lie_triple_systems).

Comment: Ternutators is a painful neologism...

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely the answer I was looking for. I'm impressed by the complexity of such a short paper. Page 618 is impressive! The referee must have had hard time...

Comment: "Ternutation" = the act of neezing.  Compare "Sternutation".

Comment: Which gives *éternuer* in French.

Answer (score 6):

One way to define a Lie structure on a vector space $V$, is as a map $\wedge^2V\to V$ such that its natural extension to $d\colon\wedge^k V\to \wedge ^{k-1}V$ satisfies $d^2=0$. This exactly gives the Jacobi identity. Similarly one can define a Lie infinity structure to be any map $d\colon \wedge V\to \wedge V$ with square $0$. In your case $[\cdot,\cdot,\cdot]_3$ gives a map 
$\wedge^k V\to\wedge^{k-2}V$ and the question becomes whether it squares to $0$, which I haven't had time to work out. But if it does, then you have a L-infinity structure.

Answer (score 5):

The proper setting is the theory of **operads**, which allows to deal with any number of generators at a single stroke.

The **Lie** operad is the sub-operad of the associative operad generated by 12-21.

There exists some n-ary Lie operads, but I do not remember whether they are exactly what you ask.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the paper "On Lie k-Algebras" by P. Hanlon by M. Wachs (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870885710389). They consider algebras satisfying the generalized Jacobi identity you specify. I wanted to leave this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.