# Replacing the Lie commutator with something else

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Take a vector space $V={A,B,C,...}$ (of matrices), and the commutator $[A,B]=AB-BA$, then a Lie algebra of $V$ is characterized by $[V,V]$ staying in $V$. (Loosely speaking.)

What happens when you replace the commutator with some other thing (based on matrix products), again presupposing that the result stays in $V$? With the anticommutator you get Jordan algebras, so at least there *are* interesting alternatives. Take the most general form with "product dimension" two:
$<A,B>=f_1*AA+f_2*AB+f_3*BA+f_4*BB$
Has the resulting algebra already been researched (or is it pointless for whatever algebraic reason)? In both cases, a reference would come in handy.

If you go to "dimension 3", the most obvious form of a "commutritor" would be
$<A,B,C>=ABC+BCA+CAB-ACB-BAC-CBA$
Again, I'd like to know either a reference or a reason why this is no useful idea.
(Surely someone had that idea before me!)

Comment: You mean something like this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96584/ternary-lie-structure ?

Comment: This question seems basically clear to me -- I'm not sure why it was put on hold.

Comment: Some of these have been studied, though I don't know how general of a theory there is.  Non-associative products of the form AB + c BA show up as "noncommutative Jordan algebras".  There is a ternary generalization of Jordan algebras that's commonly studied because it behaves better in characteristic 2 than the usual definition.  There are some other ternary generalizations that are discussed in the first chapter of McCrimmon's book on Jordan algebras.

Comment: @arsmath To see why it was put on hold, check the edit history.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft - Thanks, you're completely right.  I should have done that before shooting my big mouth off.  Er, big keyboard off?

Comment: @UwF and arsmath: Bingo! THX for the references. (I knew it existed, but I wouldn't have known where to begin searching.)

Comment: 1. For a (generally, nonassociative) algebra A, an algebra with a new multiplication x*y = xay - ybx for some fixed elements a,b in A is called mutation. There are many papers written about mutations of various classes of algebras (Boers; Elduque, Myung with coauthors; Mallol & Varro; Montaner), and one book: A. Elduque and H.C. Myung, [Mutations of Alternative Algebras](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-94-015-8279-7), Kluwer, 1994; review: [Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 33 (1996), 227-228](http://www.ams.org/bull/1996-33-02/S0273-0979-96-00630-1/home.html)

Comment: 2. A few recent arXiv texts by Keqin Liu: arXiv:1012.2844 arXiv:1104.3954 arXiv:1207.6160; its hard to describe what he is doing there in few words, but the (seemingly interesting) constructions there apparently have some resemblance with what you are interested in (basically, they are some extended mutations with a twist).